# How To add New Quantity And Update from database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a question
how to add New quantity From database..

example....

- itemcode(theres a value here)
- itemname(theres a value here)
- brandname(theres a value here)
- quantity(NO value here when i input 10 the old quantity has been update to 20 for example);;

Sorry For newbie question..

Comment: you want to update or insert new quantity? INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);

Comment: I want to insert new quantity
How to do this
sorry for this newbie question..
thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to update the quantity , like if previous is 10 and new coming 10, then update the quantity 20 right?

Answer (score 0):

```
 update items set quantity=20 where itemcode=1
```

I am saying that we can directly place the value which we want to update. No need of using `quantity+50.`

Comment: the question is not clear enough and your answer also seem to be a bit of guessing. Can you clarify your answer or explain it a bit.

Answer (score -1):

You are asking two questions here.. First is `insert` query and another is for `update` query..

for inserting new values

`insert into items (itemcode,itemname,brandname,quantity) values (1,'item1','brand','50')`

and if you want to update item quantity than you should write

`update items set quantity = quantity+50 where itemcode = 1`

let me know if you want any further assistance.

Comment: Thanks..
But for example
I input a random number
the existing is 10
and I add new 10 quantity
the new quantity is become 20
how to do this?

Comment: you need to pass atleast one parameter in your `update` query. so that you query will come to know that it has to update the quantity for the specific item.
like `update ..... where itemname = ...` or `update ...  where itemcode = ...`